# CSGO immediately crashes on Ubuntu 22.04 when opening from Steam

Tags: steam

I recently had an issue with CSGO having a frozen black screen during startup. I looked around the internet and I found a libtcmalloc solution but when I installed the package and used ln -s in the csgo bin folder it made it so that CSGO won't bootup at all anymore. I believe this a common problem so I would appreciate if anyone knows a solution or could help diagnos the issue.

I using a Nvidia 1070 as my GPU and a Intel i5 as my CPU

Comment: This may be a good question to ask Steam support.

Comment: Can you edit your question and please share your research and be more specific and detailed about what you've already tried? To improve your chances of getting an answer to your question, you should include all relevant details and history about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was unrelated to libtcmalloc and was an issue with me not having  a nvidia driver installed.